# Are questions about specific fonts allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I was about to ask a question about whether [Marcellus](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Marcellus) is serif or sans-serif, or something else altogether. However, I don't know if that'll be on-topic for being too specific to a font and veering too far from general graphic design. **Is it on-topic to ask questions about a specific font?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that would be on topic. Here's a similar question: [Is the OCR-A sans-serif?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29318/8708). The types of font-specific questions we would want to avoid are "where can I download/buy X font?", which is much less related to design in comparison to your question.